# What does each action configuration property of CodeDeployToECS refers to in AWS CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to create an Amazon ECS (Blue Green) action (`CodeDeployToECS`) in AWS CodePipeline. This will be done using Terraform, so the actions need to be manually specified.

According to the [CodePipeline Pipeline Structure Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html) under the Action Structure Requirements in CodePipeline, a `CodeDeployToECS` action has 8 action configuration properties:

- `ApplicationName`
- `DeploymentGroupName`
- `Image1ArtifactName`
- `Image1ContainerName`
- `AppSpecTemplateArtifact`
- `AppSpecTemplatePath`
- `TaskDefinitionTemplatePath`
- `TaskDefinitionTemplateArtifact`

There were no documentations regarding the exact details of each action configuration property. I was able to infer some of the names mapping to the AWS console for the corresponding action. The mappings I was able to infer is shown below.

[image: Action Configuration Properties Mapping]

However, two action configuration properties still remains a mystery; the `Image1ArtifactName` and the `Image1ContainerName` properties. What do these two fields refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `aws-cli`, I can confirm that `Image1ArtifactName` corresponds to the top text field labelled 'Input artifact with image details' while `Image1ContainerName` corresponds to the lower text field labelled 'Place holder text in the task definition'.

I did the confirmation by creating another CodePipeline and running `aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name my-pipeline` to get the details of the pipeline in JSON format, which was pretty easy to decipher the fields mapping.